# Twilio flex 2.0 theme

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

How do I configure custom theming in Twilio flex 2.0?

I tried custom theming as Flex 1.0 but it's not working anymore after migrating Flex 1.0 to 2.0

```html
import { VERSION } from '@twilio/flex-ui';
import { FlexPlugin } from '@twilio/flex-plugin';
import { ConnectorHelper } from './helpers/ConnectorHelper';
import ConnectorColorTheme from './theme/ConnectorColorTheme';
import reducers, { namespace } from './states';
import { StylesProvider, createGenerateClassName } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const PLUGIN_NAME = 'ConnectorPlugin';

export default class ConnectorPlugin extends FlexPlugin {
  constructor() {
    super(PLUGIN_NAME);
  }

  async init(flex, manager) {

    const configuration = {
      colorTheme: ConnectorColorTheme
    };

    // apply theme
   manager.updateConfig(configuration);
   }
 }
```

```css
export default {
    baseName: "FlexLight",
    colors: {
        base0: "#000000",
        base1: "#222222",
        base2: "#444444"
    },
    overrides: {
        MainHeader: {
            Container: {
                background: "#2f5771",
                color: "#ffffff"
            }
        },
        MainHeaderProfile: {
            marginRight: "1.25rem",
            width: "40px",
            height: "40px",
        },
        mainContainer: {
            width: "290px"
          },
        SideNav: {
            Container: {
                background: "#4a4e60"
            },
            Button: {
                background: "#4a4e60"
            },
        }
    }
}
```

Above code was working fine in Flex 1.0 but now I am not able to customize my theme.

Answer (score 0):

Hi yeah I noticed the same issue, what has happened is in the upgrade twilio have reworked how theming is done. with their move to their own styling libary: Twilio paste they wanted to make it more consistent.

they have renamed the properties:

- colorTheme -> theme
- overrides -> componentThemeOverride

> New theming structure promotes consistency, customization, and web accessibility. See [Theme and Branding](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/developer/plugins/migration-guide#theme-and-branding) for a list of configuration and property changes.

full list of changes [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/developer/ui/20-enhancements)